# Image visibility one

Tags: javascript, css, visibility

I have a few images with: `visibility:hidden` and an `onClick` event which sets its visibility to `visible`. Images have an id of `Img_(somenumber)`

How can I make so that when one image is visible all others should be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you could try the following:

- Add a class to the set of images you want to manipulate their visibility. e.g.

Then for each image you could to the following for the onclick event:

```
<img src="{img_src}" class="myImages" onclick="$('img.myImages').hide(); $(this).show();" />
```

The above, of course, requires that you change each image tag.

If you cannot do that (large number of images), then try using a function that will be triggered when the document loads and will add a handler for the 'onclick' event of each image. Again this easy easily achieved using jquery or another js library.

Comment: I would like to do plain js if possible, please look at: http://jsbin.com/acahu3/edit there's an example in html on how it looks like, that's the way it is, the only thing is I don't know the exact ID of each image other then I know that it begins with "Img_"

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to do this. I'm pretty sure you will want to think through it more. BUT, For an answer without jQuery. Add this as your onClick handler. Make sure you pass the this keyword.

```
<img onclick="toggleVisible(this);" src="" />
```

Include this function in your page somewhere:

```
function toggleVisible(clickedLI) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var i = imgs.length;
    while (i--) {
        var img = imgs[i];
        if (img.id.indexOf('Img_' == 0)) { 
            img.style.visibility = img.parentNode == clickedLI ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        }
    }
}
```

The first problem you will run into is that there is no way to bring back the hidden images. They are there, taking up space in the document, but they won't respond to the click events (at least not in Chrome.) Consider giving more detail in your question. As andreas said, if you have a lot of images there are more efficient ways.

Comment: Right, so that is why onclick event is on the "li" element and not on the pic itself, but something doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/acahu3/3/edit

Comment: problem with jQuery is that I already have prototype.. and it messes things up...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were putting them on the LI. Here is a fixed example.
http://jsbin.com/acahu3/4/edit